# Save new user via IP alone (anonymous, like Yik Yak)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble creating users via IP. No logins, no signups, just like Yik Yak. I'm only able to create users in the terminal, but I can't seem to translate that to the code.

In the terminal I can successfully create users by doing this:

```
irb(main):001:0> user=User.new
=> #<User id: nil, current_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> user.current_ip="159.5.159.11"
=> "159.5.159.11"
irb(main):003:0> user.save
```

Here's what I have at this point. I can't get my ip to save as a new user when I run it in rails server. What am I missing here?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :users

root 'users#create'
```

users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
cattr_accessor :current_ip

 ....

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
@user.current_ip=request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
@user.save

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

application_controller

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception

 before_filter :set_current_ip

 protected
 def set_current_ip
    @user.current_ip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
 end

end
```

Here's the error I'm currently getting

[image]

traced to
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `set_current_ip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like @user isn't set to anything yet in 'def set_current_ip'.

You probably want to do something like this (in rails 4)

```
def set_current_ip
  @user = User.where(current_ip: request.remote_ip).first_or_create
end
```

Important to note:

Tracking user's by IP like this might be brittle. IP's can change, and multiple people behind a router via NAT could all have the same IP.

I don't have a great alternative suggestion at the moment, sorry!

Comment: Thanks that corrected the application controller error but I'm still getting this issue in the users_controller, which I'll add above

Comment: That bug in the users_controller happens when the form you are submitting doesn't have a 'users' param in it. Take a look at the form that posts to the create action on users_controller. Is it a "form_for @user"?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'd say your 'mental model' of rails isn't sharp enough yet, you could benefit from following a few more tutorials and sticking close to the steps and guides first. When learning its good to first learn the rules and then later 'break' or deviate from them :D

Comment: Yes I'm new to programming, only a few months of experience.  I solved that issue by removing user_params altogether. It's capturing a new user but it's only saving the ip as "1" and not my actual ip address. Thoughts on this?

Comment: nevermind, after some googling I found that that's the default localhost IP

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're missing the `current_ip` column in your database. Are you sure you've applied the relevant migrations? Have you tried restarting your Rails server process to see if that picks up the change?

As a note, use [`request.remote_ip`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/RemoteIp.html) instead of directly accessing the `ENV` variable. The remote IP of a request can actually come from one of several environment variables.

Comment: Usually I add a `build_user` method that triggers on `new` and `create` that populates `@user` to be sure it's valid. Also add `return unless @user` to your `set_current_ip` method to be sure that doesn't trip unless it's defined, and then manually call it in your `create` method.